Angular server side renders pages multiple times after navigating to it and from it
Angular 18, i build my app with npm run build --configuration docker which triggers angular default builder :
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",

I have ssr enabled on that build :
    "ssr": {
      "entry": "server.ts"
    }

Server.ts :
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';
import express from 'express';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { dirname, join, resolve } from 'node:path';
import bootstrap from './src/main.server';
import { VERSION } from './src/environments/version';
import { BUILD } from './src/environments/build';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const serverDistFolder = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
  const browserDistFolder = resolve(serverDistFolder, '../browser');
  const indexHtml = join(serverDistFolder, 'index.server.html');

  const commonEngine = new CommonEngine();

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', browserDistFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get(
    '*.*',
    express.static(browserDistFolder, {
      maxAge: '1y',
    })
  );

  // health check endpoint
  server.get('/status', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'up',
      message: 'Service is operational',
      version: VERSION,
      build: BUILD,
      versionTag: `${VERSION}-${BUILD}`,
    });
  });

  // All regular routes use the Angular engine
  server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const authToken = req.headers['authorization']; // Retrieve authentication token from request headers
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;
    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: browserDistFolder,
        providers: [
          { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl },
          { provide: 'RESPONSE', useValue: res },
          { provide: 'AUTH_TOKEN', useValue: authToken }, // Pass authentication token as a provider
        ],
      })
      .then((html) => {
        console.log('SSR rendered page:', req.url); // Log the requested URL
        res.send(html);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('SSR rendering error:', err);
        next(err);
      });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 5200;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

run();

After i run the app with node dist/server/server.mjs everything seems normal, but then i started to log it and for example I see that some pages load multiple times that causes CPU spikes in the server. It seems that angular's server side rendering renders pages X times for each .css.map file ?? Or I dont understand something : What causes this ?


In this image you can see that SHOP PAGE INITIATED called multiple times - same as .css.map files below. Even thoguht it should be loaded once.
Shop.component.ts :
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('SHOP PAGE INITIATED');
  }


it's running on the server-side and getting all that data before serving back the static page. So endpoints are called and are probably returning observables... your subscriptions are returning at different times and when done, it can serve static... so seems normal. (ngOnInit would normally fire before subscriptions return values so client can immediately see the page... in SSR they won't see until data comes in) Where are your subscriptions placed?

It's an empty page without any subscriptions. (I recreated it without any logic inside and any html).
I just added this line  to the server.ts , so it would skip .map files, and it loads normally.:
if (originalUrl.endsWith('.map')) {
  // Skip SSR for .map files
  return next();
}

Dont know if it's an actual fix, but it works for now.

ahhh... .map files would only be for debugger methinks.  So you can probably leave those out entirely for production.  I guess it's lazy-loading those??
